# Deal with space in pathname in cmd

Tags: cmd, parameter-passing

```
C:\Program Files\mu-repo>mu
python: can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory


C:\Program Files\mu-repo>cat mu.bat
@echo off
python %~dp0\mu %*
```

When I change the `mu.bat` to have the absolute pathname of `mu.bat`, the batch file can be found:

```
C:\Program Files\mu-repo>cat mu.bat
@echo off
python "C:\Program Files\mu-repo"\mu %*

C:\Program Files\mu-repo>mu
Commands:

* mu register repo1 repo2: Registers repo1 and repo2 to be tracked.
* mu register --all: Registers all subdirs with .git (non-recursive).
```

How can I keep using `%~dp0`, without replacing it with the absolute pathname?

Thanks.

Comment: enclose paths/filenames in double quotes: `"%~dp0"`, mabe even `"%*"`

Comment: and *please* enclose the whole path\filename, not only part of it: `python "C:\Program Files\mu-repo\mu.bat" %*` or `python "%~dp0mu.bat" %*`

Comment: `python "%~dp0mu" %*` (note that `%~dp0` is already ended by `\ `on its own)

Comment: @Stephan: Do _not_ double-quote `%*` when passing arguments through - it changes the command line. While double-quoting the _whole_ argument certainly doesn't hurt, it isn't generally necessary; in this case, it isn't.

Comment: @mklement0 : therefore I said "maybe" - depends heavily on what's needed.

Comment: @Stephan: If by "maybe" you mean: change the semantics of the pass-through arguments by blindly attempting to pass them as a _single_ argument, then yes, but I would consider mentioning this - exotic and brittle - scenario here a distraction.

Answer (score 1):

Change `mu.bat` to the following:

```
@echo off
python "%~dpn0" %*
```

- The enclosing `"..."` ensures that the path is recognized as a single argument, even if it contains spaces.
- Note that I've added `n` to `%~dp0`, which adds the batch file's filename *root* (the filename without extension) - `mu`, in this case - to the resulting path, resulting in `C:\Program Files\mu-repo\mu` overall.

A few asides:

- The syntax of expressions such as `%~dp0` - a modified reference to `%0`, which contains the path to the batch file *as invoked* - is explained when you run `help call`.
  As [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) points out in a comment on the question, the `d` part expands to the directory path *including* a trailing `\`, so there is no need to append one.
- Do *not* double-quote `%*` (`"%*"`) to pass all arguments through, as that results in a different command line - just use `%*` as-is (unquoted).
- It is permissible to *mix* double-quoted and unquoted parts in a single argument; given that `mu` by itself doesn't need double-quoting, both `"%~dp0"mu` and `"%~dp0mu"` would work.